# Shorter way of adding multiple elements in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm currently adding buttons, textfields etc. to my application. This is what I currently have:

```
    add(update);
    add(updateText);
    add(afhalen);
    add(opneemText);
    add(saldo);
```

Can I write this code shorter? I have many more elements to add and it just doesn't like nice.

Comment: GUI creation is generally always ugly tedious code

Comment: What is that `add` method? Is it local to the class?

Comment: be careful with overengineered solutions given as answers. How many such lines you have usually? If it is in single digits, KISS (keep it simple and stupid) and you win on readability

Answer (score 0):

You could store your components in an array of JComponents (or any Collections such as a List), and then loop through it doing (here using an array) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < componentsArary.length; i++)
    add(componentsArary[i]);
```

That's pretty much the only other solution I can think of.

Comment: but you have to add every element to the array which is kinda the same

Comment: Sure, but whatever he does he will have to do something that's looking more or less like this, he can't avoid adding them in a Collection of some sort

Answer (score 0):

pverload the method and use list or varargs.

```
public void add(JComponent a) {
     // todo
}
public void add(JComponent a, JComponent... b) {
     // todo      
}
```

then you can do:

```
add(update, updateText, afhalen, opneemText, saldo);
```

or using an array:

```
 JComponent[] s = ...;
 JComponent y = ...;
 add(y, s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can init like this:

```
List<YourObject> aList = Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3 ....);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first collect those JComponents(?) in a list:

List myComponents = Arrays.asList(comp1, comp2, ...);

and then do:

```
for (JComponent comp : myComponents) {
  add(comp);
```

for example.